# Python appending a list to dataframe as element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe is given below

```
df = 

index    data1
0         20
1         30
2         40
```

I want to add a new column and each element consiting a list.

My expected output is

```
df = 

index    data1    list_data
0         20       [200,300,90]
1         30       [200,300,90,78,90]
2         40       [1200,2300,390,89,78]
```

My present code:

```
        df['list_data'] = []
        df['list_data'].loc[0] = [200,300,90]
```

Present output:

```
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of index')

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `loc` this way:

```
df['list_data'] = ''
df.loc[0, 'list_data'] = [200,300,90]
```

Comment: `df['list_data'] = []' is this wrong? `df['list_data'] = ""` is this correct? Because after correcting this, I got the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I added a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997554/python-how-to-combine-two-columns-of-a-dataframe-into-a-single-list

Comment: @Mainland Answered

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Series` for your problem

```
import pandas as pd
lis = [[200, 300, 90], [200, 300, 90, 78, 90], [1200, 2300, 390, 89, 78]]
lis = pd.Series(lis)
df['list_data'] = lis
```

This gives the following output

```
   index   data1    list_data
0   0        20    [200, 300, 90]
1   1        30    [200, 300, 90, 78, 90]
2   2        40    [1200, 2300, 390, 89, 78]
```