# Python how to combine two columns of a dataframe into a single list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as given below

```
df = 

index    data1    data2
0         20       120
1         30       456
2         40       34
```

How to combine two columns in above df into a single list such that first row elements come first and then second row.

My expected output

```
my_list = [20,120,30,456,40,34]
```

My code:

```
list1 = df['data1'].tolist()
list2 = df['data2'].tolist()

my_list = list1+list2
```

This did not work?

Comment: Is the order of ```my_List``` fixed? Or it can be in any order? ```list1 + list2``` gives ```[20, 30, 40, 120, 456, 34]```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That doesn't work since it won't add by same index, use the below list comprehension:

```
print([x for i in zip(df['data1'], df['data2']) for x in i])
```

Comment: `chain` is another good alternative if you want to do this the 
 python way: `[*chain.from_iterable(df[['data1', 'data2']].values.tolist())]` Edit: I see ALollz covered it already ;-)

Answer (score 5):

The underlying numpy array is organized `array([[row1], [row2], ..., [rowN]])` so we can `ravel` it, which should be very fast.

```
df[['data1', 'data2']].to_numpy().ravel().tolist()
#[20, 120, 30, 456, 40, 34]
```

---

Because I was interested: Here are all the proposed methods, plus another with chain, and some timings for making your output from 2 columns vs the length of the DataFrame.

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (n, 2))), 
    kernels=[
        lambda df: df[[0, 1]].to_numpy().ravel().tolist(),
        lambda df: [x for i in zip(df[0], df[1]) for x in i],
        lambda df: [*chain.from_iterable(df[[0,1]].to_numpy())],
        lambda df: df[[0,1]].stack().tolist()  #  proposed by @anky_91
    ],
    labels=['ravel', 'zip', 'chain', 'stack'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(20)],
    equality_check=np.allclose,  
    xlabel="len(df)"
)
```

[image]

Comment: @anky_91 Haha more I thought `chain` was going to be fast, realized U10's was way better and simpler, then wanted to see if there was anything else. Probably way too over-engineered for such a problem, but I was bored and curious.

Comment: yeah :) pandas and numpy methods are sometimes slower than vanilla  version  , especially for such cases - very helpful research

Comment: Very clean answer. The timeit comparisons are like gold dust in answers.